# APNS use with topics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an iOS notifications using `APNS` server. I can send notification to a device from server very well by DeviceToken.

I want to send notification for multiple devices at once. Is the best way to use topics messages like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)? Is there any way to send push notification like using topics in APNS ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is a ready made solution available for APNs. I have implemented based on custom publisher/subscriber pattern to handle multiple device notification based on expressions (can be topic also). But purely custom implementation.